# Accessing iPhone call history on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, abaddressbook, abperson

Is there any way to access the last time an `ABAddressBook` contact was accessed, interacted with, called, miss-called, etc.

I'm aware of the `ABPerson` properties, specifically [kABPersonModificationDateProperty](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html#jumpTo_54).  But I was wondering if there any way of knowing more about the users interaction with that contact.

Comment: Only on jailbroken devices. But i am not suggesting to do that, i am against any kind of jailbreaking of iOS devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No apple does not allow access to the Call list. Since a call information is stored in the call and not in the addressbook there is no way to get the information you want from the addressbook.

Comment: I thought so.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can access called history in iOS, especially after iOS 4. You can however know that a phone call was dialled using CoreTelephony framework.

I do it in applicationDidBecomeActive of my AppDelegate.m

```
...
    typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self;
        self.center = [[CTCallCenter alloc]init];
        self.center.callEventHandler = ^(CTCall *call) {
            if(call.callState == CTCallStateDialing) {
                weakSelf.callWasMade = YES;
            }
        };
...
```